# How to save directly to a folder a CSV file using NodeJs?

Tags: node.js

How to save a CSV file directly to a folder destination?

Currently my code prompts the save window in the browser, I DO NOT want that.

I want NodeJS to save the CSV directly to a folder destination

How can I do that?

```
var fs = require('fs');
var express = require('express');
csv = require('express-csv');
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var async = require('async');
var app     = express();

app.get('/scraper', function(req, res){
    var offset = req.query.offset || 0;
    var limit = req.query.limit || 50;

    if(gCounter === 0){
        getStreamerInfo(offset, limit, function(response){
            console.log("FILE READY!");
            res.csv(response); // this export to browser but I want to save directly to a folder
        });
    }

});
```

Comment: Could you please add the getStreamerInfo function code?

Comment: i think you can not do that because it depends on the client's browser. to do that client must uncheck the option `ask where to save each file before downloading`. Please check: http://www.howtogeek.com/231002/how-to-change-the-chrome-download-folder-location/

Answer (score 1):

Jus in case someone is looking for the same answer, this is what I did:

```
            var fs = require('fs');
            var jsonexport = require('jsonexport');
            jsonexport(response,function(err, csv){
                fs.writeFile("C:/outcome/c.csv", csv, function(err) {
                    if(err) {}
                });
            });
            //res.csv(response);
```